# If div inside other divs hasClass, addClass to top level div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question.
I currently have a bunch of divs inside my sidebar.

**The structure is like this:**
div.toggle-container > div > div.showme > div.berocket_single_filter_widget

This divs are generated from a wordpress plugin to show product filters.
Sometimes when a filter is empty the class below is added.

div.bapf_mt_none

**So the structure then becomes:**

div.toggle-container > div > div.showme > div.berocket_single_filter_widget.div.bapf_mt_none

Im trying to add a class with jQuery so that when
if the class.div.bapf_mt_none exists inside these other divs.
I want to add a class to div.toggle-container

But im stuck.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your attempt, and we'll tell you what is it you did incorrectly

Comment: Add `HTML` please and your attempt as well ?

Comment: `$(".bapf_mt_none").closest(".toggle-container").addClass(".empty")`

Comment: Hi there,

I now have this:

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if ( jQuery("div").hasClass("bapf_mt_none") ) {
        jQuery(".toggle-container").addClass("darkmenu")};
});

But then the class .darkmenu is added to every .toggle-container div. 

Even if the class.bapf_mt_none does not exist

Comment: $(".bapf_mt_none").closest(".toggle-container").addClass(".empty")

This did the trick!!!

Comment: $(".bapf_mt_none").closest(".toggle-container").addClass(".empty")

This did the trick.

Thanks freedomn-m!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to add a class when the class.div.bapf_mt_none exists inside these other divs. I want to add a class to div.toggle-container

You could go with a solution that takes the top `.toggle-container`, then looks inside the structure to find where `.berocket_single_filter_widget` has `.bapf_mt_none`, alternatively, you could look directly for `.bapf_mt_none` then navigate up to add the class to the container:

```
$(".bapf_mt_none").closest(".toggle-container").addClass(".empty");
```

(using .empty as an example)

If you find `.bapf_mt_none` occurs in places other than your filter, you can be more specific in the selector, eg:

```
$("div.toggle-container > div > div.showme > div.berocket_single_filter_widget.div.bapf_mt_none")
    .closest(".toggle-container")
    .addClass(".empty");
```

but the concept is the same - look for the bottom level and, thanks to the way jquery works, it will then apply to all matching parents for all elements found.   If none found, `.empty` (in the example) won't be applied.